# Eliminar especificos caracteres en todas las columnas en un dataframe de panda

Tags: python, pandas, replace, apply

Tengo la siguiente df

```
Compression_level Size  Real time  User time  Sys tine
0                  0  265  0m19.938s  0m24.649s  0m3.062s
1                  1   76  0m17.910s  0m25.929s  0m3.098s
2                  2   74  0m20.619s  0m27.724s  0m3.014s
3                  3   73  0m20.607s  0m27.937s  0m3.193s
4                  4   67  0m19.598s  0m28.853s  0m2.925s
5                  5   67  0m21.032s  0m30.119s  0m3.206s
6                  6   66  0m27.013s  0m31.462s  0m3.106s
7                  7   65  0m27.337s  0m36.226s  0m3.060s
8                  8   64  0m37.651s  0m47.246s  0m2.933s
9                  9   64  0m59.241s   1m8.333s  0m3.027s
```

Y me gustaría eliminar el "0m" y el "s" de todas las columnas. Se hacer un replace columna por columna de la siguiente forma

`data["Real time"] = data["Real time"].replace({'0m':''}, regex=True)`

pero tengo muchas columnas además me gustaria que fuera un código mas elegante y no ir repitiendo el código anterior tantas veces como columnas tengo.

Podría alguien ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**La solución que propone es correcta**, si agregas una lista de columnas en las cuales quieres remover el caracter resolverá la eliminación del mismo sin iterar por cada columna, ej:

```
# columnas donde quiero remover caracteres:
columnas = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df[columnas] = df[columnas].replace({'0m':''}, regex=True)
```